# How is the pair of adjoint functors defined in this ncat article?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, online-resources

I'm trying to read the article about [spaces and quantities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/space+and+quantity) on ncat.
I find it very interesting, but I'm afraid I can't follow how technically they are defining the functors –
either because it's supposed to be an informal exposition, or because they are throwing around Yoneda embeddings way too liberally for me, or both!

Take a category $S$, and call $P:=\operatorname{Set}^{S^\text{op}}$ and $Q:=\operatorname{Set}^S$.

They claim that there is a pair of functors, $C: P^\text{op} \to Q$ and $\operatorname{Spec}: Q\to P^\text{op}$, that are adjoint.

But how are they defined? I.e. if I have a presheaf (on $S$) $X$, what is the copresheaf (on $S$) $C(X)$?

Sorry I know it's just written there. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Given a presheaf $X$ and an object $U$ of $S$, we have $X(U)=\mathrm{Mor}(U_{.},X)$ by Yoneda Lemma.

That suggests $C(X)(U)=\mathrm{Mor}(X,U_{.})$.

Note that if $X=V_{.}$, then $C(V_{.})(U)=\mathrm{Mor}(V,U)$, so $C(V_{.})=V^{.}$.

Comment: Ahh.. Ok i see! So in the same way, is it that $\operatorname{Spec}(Y)(U)=\mathrm{Mor}(Y,C(U_{.}))$ for any copresheaf $Y$? If so, I get it then.